# Writing to a file asynchronously, but in order

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've got some code which saves data from an object to XML. This locked the UI for a few seconds so I made it so it wouldn't.

```
foreach (Path path in m_canvasCompact.Children)
{
   Task.Run(() => WritePathDataToXML(false, path));
}

Private void WritePAthDataToXML(bool is32x32, Path path)
{

   //stuff going on... 

   xmlDoc.Root.Descendants.......Add(iconToAdd);
   xmlDoc.Save(..);
}
```

The problem is (as expected) the order in which the data is written to the XML is in a random order depending upon the speed in which the tasks finish (I assume)

I could probably write some bodged code which looks at the XML and rearranges it once everything has been completed, but that's not ideal. Is there anyway to do this on a separate thread, but perhaps only one at a time, so they get executed and saved in the correct order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a producer/consumer queue. You can rig that up fairly easily using [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312).

1. Create the blocking collection
2. Start a task which will read from the collection until it's "finished" (simplest with [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381957)), writing to the file
3. Add all the relevant items to the collection - making sure you do *everything* that touches UI elements within the UI thread.
4. Tell the collection it's "finished" ([`CompleteAdding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086(v=vs.110).aspx))

Alternatively, as suggested in comments:

- In the UI thread, create a collection with all the information you need from UI elements - basically you don't want to touch the UI elements within a non-UI thread.
- Start a task to write that collection to disk; optionally await that task (which won't block the UI)

That's simpler, but it does mean building up the whole collection in memory before you start writing. With the first approach, you can add to the collection as you write - although it's entirely possible that if building the collection is much faster than writing to disk, you'll end up with the whole thing in memory anyway. If this is infeasible, you'll need some way of adding "gently" from the UI thread, without blocking it. It would be nice if `BlockingCollection` had an `AddAsync` method, but I can't see one.

We don't know enough about what you're doing with the `Path` elements to give you sample code for this, but hopefully that's enough of a starting point.

Comment: @zaitsman: That *is* a FIFO queue - but a thread-safe one which allows easy polling etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have no idea what any of that means (Only just started your Async series of Pluralsight) but I'll spend some time Googling. Thanks.

Comment: Does one need a blocking collection? I see one task which is filling the collection, probably the main task; and another -- single -- task which does the writing to file. That writing task is not started before the main task is done filling the collection, which is fast (as opposed to the actual writing).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I guess if we're happy to put *all* the information required from the UI thread into a single collection in memory beforehand, that works - and even if we're not, I haven't said anything about limiting the size. Will add that as another option.

Answer (score 0):

Run the whole loop in a `Task`:

```
Task.Run(()=>{
    foreach (Path path in m_canvasCompact.Children)
    {
       WritePathDataToXML(false, path);
    }
});
```

This will still take the same time, but should not block the UI.

Comment: That's accessing UI elements (`m_canvasCompact.Chlidren`) in the UI thread, as far as I can see. At least assuming that `m_canvasCompact` is a UI element...

Comment: @Jon - Good point, thanks. If it is a UI element, we can still extract the `Children` list before creating the task, and loop over it in the other thread, so I think there's a simple workaround. I'm assuming the OP's code works.

Comment: Right - as per the second approach in my answer.